# Apache Kafka broker's OOM when rebalancing partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, out-of-memory

We have a Kafka region cluster of 14 brokers (on AWS instances), 53 topics by 128 partitions each. Last time when we added 3 new brokers, during partitions rebalance multiple brokers became OOM and had to be force-killed.

Kafka version is `1.1.0` (2.11-1.1.0).
Replication factor 3, log retention 1 week.

The memory heap size is set to 8G. Box has 244G memory available (`d2.8xlarge` instance type).

Java memory configuration:

```
-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent 
-Xms8G -Xmx8G -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m
-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80
```

The questions are:

- what could cause OOM?
- how much memory should we allocate to Kafka brokers or what should we do to avoid OOM?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to collect heapdumps on OOM and check what was using the heap. Also if you have 200+GB of memory, depending what you find analyzing the heap and what else is running on the machines, you could just increase the heap size.

Comment: Thanks, @MickaelMaison. Yeah, we are going to set `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` for future cases along with trying to reproduce the issue on a test cluster.